# how does vagrant get information about the VM

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, provisioning

I have been using vagrant for some time now and have came across "bugs" that I would like to understand more in depth.

the situation I encountered was that when provisioning a base box that I have created the /etc/exports file was loaded with the wrong IP, The file was given the IP the base box had while I was creating it, And once I packaged the base box, every time I did "vagrant up" and provisioned it there was an error because vagrant used the IP the base box had and the new box I was spinning up had a different (random) IP that i wanted vagrant to use.

So my question is, where does vagrant or virtualbox hold that data about the base box? why does it sometimes "stick" like that and sometimes doesn't? And when I'll understand where that data is stored, Is it holding any more data I can manipulate?

Comment: In the `vagrantfile` like `wm.config.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.0.1"?

Comment: Thanks but no, im using : "config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp" and VM gets a random ip but the /etc/exports file is sometimes loaded with the same ip, the ip the base box had while packaging it. sometimes i must of packaged it differently and it dosent happen, i want to understand at wich point im doing something wrong and where is this data stored.